# VSCode colon open command palette

Tags: visual-studio-code

On my Mac OS, I install VIM for vs code.

After press colon ':', vs code command palette pops up, no enter vim command on status bar. And on status bar a string 'workbench.action.showCommands' shows.  I think that indicates somewhere I set up colon as a shortcut to vscode command.

VIM extension works fine on my Windows.

Where can I find the wrong settings and get vim colon work?

Answer (score 0):

There is a key mapping setting for VIM extension in my settings.json. Can't remember where it is from. Remove it solves the problem.

```
{
    "before": [":"],
    "commands": [
        "workbench.action.showCommands"
    ]
},
```